# Spring Batch Admin with Spring 4.3.7

Tags: spring, spring-batch

Do you know what version of Spring Batch Admin is supported by Spring 4? We recently upgraded to Spring 4.3.7 and running into issues using version 1.3.1 of Spring Batch Admin.
Thanks,
Radmila

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are not compatible, and there is no newer version. It is not known if there will be any further development. The general suggestion is to take a look of Spring Cloud Data Flow.

On the other hand, take a look at this: https://github.com/tuxdevelop/spring-batch-lightmin . I am not familiar with it, but it may help.

Comment: Thank. We need rest services that spring batch admin provides not so much ui.

Comment: The way we solved it is by adding spring-integration dependencies that matched our spring 4.3.7 version. By default spring-batch-admin brings in spring-integration version 3 that was not compatible with spring 4.3.7.